# Weird discrepancy between git and github

Tags: git, github

I have a weird discrepancy between my local files and my Github code. I have only recently started my rails project, which you can find [here](http://github.com/yebudar/french). The thing is, the code that you see is a few commits older than the files I have locally. I have tried staging, committing and running `git status` but it makes no difference. I have also run `git pull` but it says all the code is up to date. The even weirder part is that when I run `git push origin master` (also tried `-u`) it gives me a hint to run `git pull` (which, of course, does nothing).

I have checked the remote and everything looks fine (I have managed to push code to it in the past and I have not messed with the remotes since it stopped working). The first time I remember it not working was when I pushed some changes I had made, and then logged off (without checking github) to do something else. I came back later but I was intrigued to find that my code hadn't been pushed.

I know this is just me being dumb but I can't for the life of me work out what is wrong! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had this happen before.  My memory is I asked Github about it and they said that their web-front-end can occasionally fall behind.  Check out your repository into a new directory from github.  If that's up to date then you don't (really) have anything to worry about.

If it isn't, we either need to see more git output or you should submit a ticket.